# Sessions are set, but links aren't working

Tags: php, jquery

So when the links are clicked, it triggers the **query** at the bottom of the page to `hide` the `div`, and the `session` variable is set for the menu state. However my `<a>` link tags doesn't seem to be working.

The links work if I add `href=""`, but then, when they are clicked, they just refresh the page and doesn't trigger the query at the bottom of the page.

I have this **PHP** at the top of my page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['menu_state'])) {$_SESSION['menu_state'] = $_GET['menu_state'];}
?>
```

Then a little further down I have:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["menu_state"] == 'visable')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $page_cont = '';
    $nav = 'style="display:block;"';
}
elseif($_SESSION["menu_state"] == 'hidden')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $page_cont = 'width:100%;';
    $nav = 'style="display:none;"';
}
elseif($_SESSION["menu_state"] == '')
{
    $show_menu = 'style="display:none;"';
    $hide_menu = 'style="display:block;"';
    $page_cont = '';
    $nav = 'style="display:block;"';
}
?>

<div class="show_menu" <?php echo $show_menu; ?>><a>Show Menu</a></div>
<div class="hide_menu" <?php echo $hide_menu; ?>><a>Hide Menu</a></div>
```

And at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript.php">
$('.show_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("margin-left", "200px");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "block");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "none");
   jQuery('#div_session_write').load('headervertical.php?menu_state=visable');
});
$('.hide_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("margin-left", "0");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "none");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "block");
   jQuery('#div_session_write').load('headervertical.php?menu_state=hidden');
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Make sure to add the href and add preventDefault to the click functions this will stop it from refreshing the page.

Also you have the class for your click events set on the div not the a tag. So jquery is never getting called I would put a class or I'd on the a tag and make that be the object you check for a click event on.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="show_menu"><a></a></div>
```

should be

```
<div><a class="show_menu" href=""></a></div>
```

you are telling jquery you are clicking a div layer when you are clicking a link inside that div layer.

Comment: ok so i have added e.preventDefault(); and also tried preventDefault(); to the jquery code at the bottom just under $('.hide_menu').click(function() { and $('.show_menu').click(function() { plus i added a href="" and a href="#" but nothing works still. the page still refreshes and the menu does not set display:none

Comment: You need to have the link be what is being clicked not the div tag.